# JavaScript TypeError: ele("XYZ") is null

Tags: javascript

I have what I think should be a simple function that is returning:

> TypeError: ele("XYZ") is null

and is not returning the proper value.  In my case, element XYZ is called `AgeCount`.  Here is my script:

```
function countAgesSelected(){
    var agesSelectedCount = 0;
    if (document.myform.a4049.checked==true) {
         agesSelectedCount++;
    }
    if (document.myform.a5064.checked==true) {
         agesSelectedCount++;
    }
    if (document.myform.a65plus.checked==true) {
         agesSelectedCount++;
    }
    ele('AgeCount').value = agesSelectedCount;
}
```

Browser throws the error on that last line.

Here is relevant HTML:

```
<input name="4049" type="checkbox" value="4049" id="a4049" starweb_type="Checkbox/Radio Button" checked="checked" onclick="countAgesSelected()" />40-49
<input name="5064" type="checkbox" value="5064" id="a5064" starweb_type="Checkbox/Radio Button" checked="checked" onclick="countAgesSelected()" />50-64
<input name="65plus" type="checkbox" value="65plus" id="a65plus" starweb_type="Checkbox/Radio Button" checked="checked" onclick="countAgesSelected()" />65+
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="AgeCount" />
```

I am hoping that I just have a simple syntax error.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's `ele`? You're using it as a function, but it's not defined anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**

*Mixed up getElementsByName and getElementsByTagName, code is now updated.*

Where is the `ele` function coming from?

Use `document.getElementsByName("AgeCount")[0]` instead of the ele-function or create the ele-function like this:

```
function ele(element)
{
    return document.getElementsByName(element)[0];
}
```

Comment: Feeling like an idiot. Here's what I forgot to include in my info for this post: function ele(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } --- but I see the mistake is that I had failed to declare an id in my HTML doc for AgeCount.  Just tested and it's ok now.  Many, many thanks to all who responded, and so quickly. This is a great community.

Comment: hm? What did you forget to include?

Comment: All answers pointed me in the right direction - many thanks to all.

Comment: So finally, you only mixed up "ById" and "ByName"... No big deal ;).

Answer (score -1):

```
function countAgesSelected(){
    var agesSelectedCount = 0;
    if (document.myform.a4049.checked==true) {
         agesSelectedCount++;
    }
    if (document.myform.a5064.checked==true) {
         agesSelectedCount++;
    }
    if (document.myform.a65plus.checked==true) {
         agesSelectedCount++;
    }
    document.getElementsByName('AgeCount')[0].value = agesSelectedCount;
}
```

Sorry, read that as ID, instead of name

Comment: There is no element with the ID `AgeCount`

Comment: AgeCount is a name, not an id.